# SQL group by DATENAME

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to get a count of rows for each day of the week between a certain date.

so far I have:

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,Date) AS theDay FROM tablename WHERE year(date) = '2013' and (month(date) >= 5 AND month(date) <= 7)
```

this gives me something like this:

```
Wednesday
Wednesday
Wednesday
Wednesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Thursday
Friday
Friday
Friday
Friday
Saturday
Saturday
```

But I'd like for it to be like

```
Wednesday
```

and then in the next column

```
5
```

and so on.  I know this is a group by, but I'm not that great with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,Date) AS theDay,count(*) NumberOfDays
FROM tablename 
WHERE year(date) = '2013' and (month(date) >= 5 AND month(date) <= 7)
group by DATENAME(weekday,Date)
```

Comment: that doesn't give me the counts.  only groups the days.

Comment: If it's not giving you the counts you didn't copy it exactly.

Comment: I would caution you to use functions on columns used in the predicate as they can prevent the use of index seek operations.  Something like this will allow an index seek, WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@BeginDt),0) AND [Date] < DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@EndDt),0))]